# How ./configure Bitcoin Core build to pick up depends build and installation path at the same time?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, compiling

I'm trying to build Bitcoin Core and, if I understand it correctly, the configure script uses the `--prefix=` option twice, once for the inclusion of the depends build (from `depends/README.md`):

```
**Bitcoin Core's configure script by default will ignore the depends output.** In
order for it to pick up libraries, tools, and settings from the depends build,
you must point it at the appropriate `--prefix` directory generated by the
build. In the above example, a prefix dir named x86_64-w64-mingw32 will be
created. To use it for Bitcoin:

    ./configure --prefix=$PWD/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

And another usage of `--prefix` as it's usually used in configure, to specify a nonstandard install location (output from `./configure --help`):

```
By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.
```

How can I specify an installation path and a depends path at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the installation path with `./configure`, but only when running `make install`. You need to specify `--prefix=`once for `./configure` and once for `make install`.

Comment: `make: unrecognized option '--prefix=/home/...`

Comment: Another option might be to use `DESTDIR`: https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html. If that works, maybe you can have `--prefix=` and `DESTDIR=` in the same `./configure` command.